# Check file is uploaded or not before use multer in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

i used this code for file upload

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// for multer 

var multer  =   require('multer');  

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({  
destination: function (req, file, callback) {  
callback(null, './public/upload');   
},  
filename: function (req, file, callback) { 
var fn =  Date.now() + file.originalname.replace(/\s/g, '');
req.middlewareStorage = {
    fileimage : fn//,
    //otherKey : otherValue
  }
callback(null, fn); 

}  
});  



var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('myfile');

app.post('/userdetail/addupdaterecord',isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
 upload(req,res,function(err) {  
            if(err) {  
               // return res.end("Error uploading file.");
               res.redirect('/userdetail');
            }  
            else
            {
                // for db 
            }

        });
 });
```

here i want to check file is uploaded or not before upload function , but every time i got error file not defined.

i try with many technique but i am not found any solution please help me.

Comment: there is no another way to check file is uploaded or not.